# Prove that $2^x + 2^{|x|} \geq 2 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality

I need to prove that  $2^x + 2^{|x|} \geq 2 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Any ideas of hints about how to begin? Ps. Sorry I am new at this.

Comment: In fact I proved it for x≥0

Comment: Cases... It should prove itself.

Comment: Hint: if $a \gt 0$ then $a + 1/a \ge 2\,$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this estimate:$$2^x+\color{green}{2^{\lvert x\rvert}}-2\ge 2^x+\color{green}{2^{-x}}-2=\frac{2^{2x}-2\cdot 2^x+1}{2^x}=\frac{\left(2^x-1\right)^2}{2^{x}}\ge 0$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Use casework to get your answer. Start first with the case of positive $x$, then the case of negative $x$, and then the case of $x=0$.

It seems that you have proven it already for $x \ge 0$, so now you need to worry about negative $x$. If $x$ is negative, then
$$2^x+2^{|x|}=2^x+2^{-x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=2^x+2^{|x|}$.

If $x \ge 0$, then $2^x + 2^{|x|}=2(2^x)\ge 2(1)=2$.

If $x<0$, then $2^x + 2^{|x|}=2^x+2^{-x}=f(x)$.

$f'(x)=\ln2(2^x-2^{-x})$.

Notice that for $x<0$, this implies that.
 $f'(x)$ is strictly negative on $x \in (-\infty, 0)$. We have $f(0)=2$.

Therefore, $f(x)>2$ for all $x \in (-\infty,0)$, $f(0)=2$, and $f(x)>2$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Thus $f(x) \geq 2$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

The Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality tells us ${a+b\over2}\ge\sqrt{ab}$ if $a,b\ge0$.  Rewriting this as $a+b\ge2\sqrt{ab}$ and letting $a=2^x$ and $b=2^{|x|}$, we get

$$2^x+2^{|x|}\ge2\sqrt{2^{x+|x|}}\ge2$$

since $x+|x|\ge0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\ge 0$ then $f_1(x)=2^x+2^{|x|}=2^{x+1}\ge 2$.

When $x\lt0$ we have $f_2(x)=2^x+2^{-x}$ whose derivative is $f_2'(x)=2^{-x}(4^x -1)\ln 2$. Since $f_2'(x)=0$ clearly implies $4^x-1=0\iff x=0$ we have $f_2(x)\ge f_2(0)= 2$.

Thus $f(x)\ge2$ where $f(x)=2^x+2^{-x}=\begin{cases}2^{x+1} \text{ if}\space  x\ge0\\2^x+2^{-x} \text{ if}\space x\lt0\end{cases}$